How could I have improved this suggested edit of a Python question?
I recently proposed this edit to a Python question about converting fractions to decimals. I wanted to emphasize that the question was about Python 2, add the decimal and fractions tag, and fix a number of grammar mistakes. It received two rejection votes and one approval vote, which was enough to get it rejected.

One of the reviewers rejected it because it deviated from original intent, and the other rejected because it did not improve the quality of the post. Do you agree with this feedback? Is there a way I could've improved the edit?

I think the advice should be not to make edits on high scoring questions with multiple high scoring answers as a <2K user. I wrote about this last year here making the point that the probability of rejection increases with the score of the post.

I'd say the title edit adds nothing, the additional tags are not relevant, and the body edits improve the question.

It should be noted that you first raised this in the python chat room and you met resistance there already before this (I'm cutting out the other bits of dialogue going on):
You:

I found this question about converting fractions to decimals, but it
seems to be about Python 2.x specifically. Should I consider answering
with Python 3.x in mind? Or writing a new question altogether? Or
maybe just moving on since the question isn't really that great to
begin with?

Me:

@Anerdw I don't follow. The accepted answer specifically addresses
python 3, the difference between python 2 and about the Fraction
object. What more would there be to add?

Karl Knechtel:

@Anerdw The thing is that it isn't actually "about converting
fractions (i.e. instances of the Fraction class) to decimals (i.e.
instances of the Decimal class). It's not about "converting" at all.
It's about displaying the correct result in floating-point format
(which OP has described as "decimal") when dividing integers, and the
problem is in the calculation (hence the 2.x tag), not the actual
textual conversion for display (which is automatic).
Which is to say, neither fractions nor decimals are intended to be
involved; floating-point numbers are supposed to be involved, but
aren't because of Python 2.x's integer division. That, in turn, is a
duplicate and I've hammered it as such.
(it's also confusingly stated and nowhere near as good quality as the
canonical)

I am not the person that declined the edit, but I think you got a pretty decent overview of why such an edit was unnecessary. I'm not sure what else there would be to add in a meta discussion here.
There are still people that have to maintain Python 2.x libraries and the answers cover both bases anyway.

I think this conversation might've taken place after I proposed the edit? I'm not sure. Anyways, didn't realize the comments apply just as well to editing the original question as they did to asking a new one. Thanks.

Just to be clear, your proposed edit was almost 8 hours after Karl's message, which was the last in the conversation, and it would have notified you. Chat comments and edit comments are entirely disconnected, but the topic here was relevant

For the record: I don't think there's anything wrong in general with trying to improve duplicates, especially if they already got a handful of upvotes.

One of the reviewers rejected it because it deviated from original intent

Possibly. As I mentioned in chat (and roganjosh recapped here), the question doesn't seem to actually have to do with fractions or decimals - that was just the OP's uninformed mental model. While it might make some sense to preserve that language while cleaning things up a bit (after all, other beginners with the same problem might have the same flawed mental model!), the tag edits are not helping. (Tags are primarily for categorizing questions for the benefit of people looking for questions to answer, and somewhat to help curators choose groups of questions to curate. They don't really help external search engines, and the site search is terrible regardless.)
At any rate, it isn't really clear what OP meant by "the variable x = 1/2". You took it to mean x specifically; I took it to mean the code fragment x = 1/2 (in which case, in 2.x, the answer is no, and this is important for understanding the problem - because OP seems to have assumed the problem was in formatting, when it's actually in the calculation). It's important to understand that beginners - at a level of skill where they'll run into problems like the one described - misuse or misunderstand terminology constantly.

and the other rejected because it did not improve the quality of the post

No, I think you definitely improved the quality overall - although IMO the bit about "split functions, loops or maps" is a distraction that should have been removed. It's not quite clear what OP meant by "split functions" (perhaps the .split method of strings?) or "maps" (probably the map builtin? But dicts can potentially be referred to as "maps" in language-agnostic computer science jargon...), but more importantly it's completely unclear why OP wanted to avoid those specific tools, and also unclear why OP thought they might have been relevant to solving the problem.


I don't think the question has anything to do with fractions, which describes the concept of rational numbers. The question is about the behavior of the division operator, and not so much about the concept of rational numbers.

Adding the decimal tag doesn't hurt, but it also doesn't really improve the question. Yes, decimal numbers are used, but there is nothing in the question that requires something specific about decimal numbers compared to other number bases.

Emphasizing Python 2.x should definitely not be done in the title (actually, the "in Python" part should be removed).

A lot of stuff, like adding code formatting is ok, but also not really required.

Changing "... can someone explain me why and how to fix it?" to "Why is that happening, and what should I do instead?" is the only part that required editing.


All in all, I'd say that there are more negative points than positive points and if I would have reviewed the edit, I would have probably picked "Reject and edit" to only edit the last sentences.

'actually, the "in Python" part should be removed' - No needs to remove from the title all words which are listed as tags: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles.

IMO adding info that it's Python 2 is crucial. I know it's in tags as well, but still. Python 2 is totally different than Python 3.
